# Queue optimizations between two queues

Tags: c, multithreading, simulation, semaphore, simulator

I'll try to explain my problem best I can. I'm having trouble with the final part of a college assignment and got really stuck.

The scenario is this: we have to build a simulation of an airport, in which a thread represents a flight (either departure or arrival), and have to optimize the arrivals and departures to minimize the time that it takes flights to land or depart.

So, onto the problem. I have all structures working, threads being created in the right moment, shared memory fully functional, message queue created and working, etc.

But now, I'm struggling with actually managing the flights. I created two linked lists, one for the arrivals and one for the departures. Each node of the linked list has a pointer to a space in the shared memory. Each of those spaces has the information relative to a flight (eta and fuel for arrivals, desired takeoff for departures). The arrivals linked list is sorted by ETA, and the takeoff linked list is sorted by desired takeoff. These linked lists are supposed to be a queue.

Problem is, I have no clue on how to manage them. There can be two departures or two arrivals at the same time, but there can't be both arrivals and departures at the same time.

I'm thinking of using semaphores, but I'm not sure if that's a good approach. I'd greatly appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

We have a couple of specifications, but I thought this post would become too big as I was just looking for general headlines. In short, we have to minimize the number of times we need to order an arrival to hold (wait in the air), and "alternate between arrivals and departures to improve airport efficiency"

Comment: Why not simply let one arrival flight land, then let one departure flight start? Even if they have the same ETA/ETD just switching between the queues should work fine.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I believe we're supposed to manage them in a more efficient way, but am failing to grasp on how

Comment: "A more efficient way" is very open-ended and ambiguous, it could mean just about anything. Perhaps you need to ask your teacher or teachers assistants for clarifications.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude we have a couple of specifications, but I thought this post would become too big as I was just looking for general headlines. In short, we have to minimize the number of times we need to order an arrival to ```hold``` (wait in the air), and "alternate between arrivals and departures to improve airport efficiency".

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information, as it's crucial for understanding the problem.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about your architecture? Why do you have more than one thread?

Answer (score 0):

The specification is short. I understand this is for the purpose of keeping question small. But with this limited specification, I can only do some guess work here.

This problem seems to me similar to Old bridge problem.

> An old bridge has only one lane and can only hold at most 3 cars at a
>   time without risking collapse. Create a solution that controls traffic
>   so that at any given time, there are at most 3 cars on the bridge, and
>   all of them are going the same direction. A car calls ArriveBridge
>   when it arrives at the bridge and wants to go in the specified
>   direction (0 or 1); ArriveBridge should not return until the car is
>   allowed to get on the bridge. A car calls ExitBridge when it gets off
>   the bridge, potentially allowing other cars to get on. Don’t worry
>   about starving cars trying to go in one direction; just make sure cars
>   are always on the bridge when they can be.

If you think so, you can find the solution to this problem here:
With some modifications you may be able to use it for your air traffic problem.

https://codeistry.wordpress.com/2018/04/18/old-bridge/